# When using the ChatInterface, how to remove -or edit- the "Chatbot" leyend on top left?

Tags: gradio

The title. I would like to remove it or at least be able to edit it.
Checked documentation and inspected the rendered running app, but I am not able to find the way.

currently using:

```
aleph_ui = gr.ChatInterface(chat_streamer, 
                            submit_btn=None, 
                            stop_btn=None, 
                            retry_btn=None, 
                            undo_btn=None, 
                            clear_btn=None, 
                            css="footer {visibility: hidden}",
                            theme=gradio_theme).queue()
```